# Add bias to Lasagne neural network layers

Tags: python, neural-network, theano, lasagne

I am wondering if there is a way to add bias node to each layer in Lasagne neural network toolkit? I have been trying to find related information in documentation.

This is the network I built but i don't know how to add a bias node to each layer.

```
def build_mlp(input_var=None):
    # This creates an MLP of two hidden layers of 800 units each, followed by
    # a softmax output layer of 10 units. It applies 20% dropout to the input
    # data and 50% dropout to the hidden layers.

    # Input layer, specifying the expected input shape of the network
    # (unspecified batchsize, 1 channel, 28 rows and 28 columns) and
    # linking it to the given Theano variable `input_var`, if any:
    l_in = lasagne.layers.InputLayer(shape=(None, 60),
                                     input_var=input_var)

    # Apply 20% dropout to the input data:
    l_in_drop = lasagne.layers.DropoutLayer(l_in, p=0.2)

    # Add a fully-connected layer of 800 units, using the linear rectifier, and
    # initializing weights with Glorot's scheme (which is the default anyway):
    l_hid1 = lasagne.layers.DenseLayer(
            l_in_drop, num_units=800,
            nonlinearity=lasagne.nonlinearities.rectify,
            W=lasagne.init.Uniform())

    # We'll now add dropout of 50%:
    l_hid1_drop = lasagne.layers.DropoutLayer(l_hid1, p=0.5)

    # Another 800-unit layer:
    l_hid2 = lasagne.layers.DenseLayer(
            l_hid1_drop, num_units=800,
            nonlinearity=lasagne.nonlinearities.rectify)

    # 50% dropout again:
    l_hid2_drop = lasagne.layers.DropoutLayer(l_hid2, p=0.5)

    # Finally, we'll add the fully-connected output layer, of 10 softmax units:
    l_out = lasagne.layers.DenseLayer(
            l_hid2_drop, num_units=2,
            nonlinearity=lasagne.nonlinearities.softmax)

    # Each layer is linked to its incoming layer(s), so we only need to pass
    # the output layer to give access to a network in Lasagne:
    return l_out
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually you don't have to explicitly create biases, because `DenseLayer()`, and convolution base layers too, has a default keyword argument:

`b=lasagne.init.Constant(0.)`.

Thus you can avoid creating `bias`, if you don't want to have with explicitly pass `bias=None`, but this is not that case.

Thus in brief you do have bias parameters while you don't pass `None` to `bias` parameter e.g.:

```
hidden = Denselayer(...bias=None)
```